# ZF2 Subdirectory for controllers => view files

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to structure my project like the following:

```
MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/TestController.php 
MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/Admin/TestController.php
```

The problem is, that both controllers look for the view file **mymodule/test.phtml**, because the directory **Admin** doesn't matter. Is there a way to take care of the directory without write it down manually in each controller action?

I would like to structure it like that:

```
MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/TestController.php => view/mymodule/test.phtml
MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/Admin/TestController.php => view/mymodule/admin/test.phtml
```

Or maybe someone has an idea to structure it otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done in a previous project before. Pretty sure you can config this in the module.config.php file, maybe something like:

```
// View file paths
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map'             => array(
        'MyModule/Admin/Test' => __DIR__ . '/../view/mymodule/admin/test.phtml'
    )
)
```

Just make sure the paths are correct. However, you could just have an Admin module and have all of the admin controllers reside there that way you wouldn't have to worry about the Controller/Admin issue you are having with the view files right now. Then all of your other modules could either extend, use DI or the service mgr to get what you need from the Admin module.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default template injector with your own one where you will specify the logic that will resolve the template path for the admin controllers.

Check out my blog post covering this topic in depth with an example

http://blog.igorvorobiov.com/2014/10/18/creating-a-custom-template-injector-to-deal-with-sub-namespaces-in-zend-framework-2/